# Reduce spacing between Views in ListView in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-listview

I am a beginner Student of Android Development.
I want to reduce distance between Views in a ListView. This is my Code Sample for listView in `numberActivity`:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.NumbersActivity"/>
```

**And This is My Custom listView Code:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#78909C"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageID"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/miwokText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#65747C"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/defaultText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#65747C"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#E4E495"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define `android:padding="8dp"` on your Main **LinearLayout** because you are giving padding to the four directions (up, down, left and right). Instead you could apply it to your left and right and bottom but not top and like this you could have your items a little bit closer.
some like this:

```
    android:paddingBottom ="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft ="8dp"
    android:paddingRight ="8dp"
```

Also, try using **margin** insted of **padding**